# How to handle swift protobuf(Static library) dependency in xcframework generation

Tags: ios, swift, xcodebuild, xcframework, swiftprotobuf

I have a SDK called **ParentSDK** and it have some dependency are swift-protobuf(Static library) and some private frameworkSDKs. Already add a podFile in my **ParentSDK**. Add all framework installation cocoa pod cmd in my podFile include swiftprotobuf. Compile and successfully generate xcFramework in my **ParentSDK**.

Then use my generated **ParentSDK** xcFramework in my XCodeApplication and try to run my application.

I have a crash while application launch, so can't run my application.

**Crash log**

```
dyld[8182]: Symbol not found: _$s13SwiftProtobuf19_ProtoNameProvidingP17_protobuf_nameMapAA01_dH0VvgZTq
  Referenced from: /Users/<Mac-Name>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C1C95FC4-20C5-4C06-94D2-EFA435B83C04/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/97C2C91F-DDC8-49AE-8DE1-157C552B394D/XCWorkspaceBuildGenerationPractise.app/Frameworks/<ParentSDK>.framework/<ParentSDK>
  Expected in: /Users/<Mac-Name>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C1C95FC4-20C5-4C06-94D2-EFA435B83C04/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/97C2C91F-DDC8-49AE-8DE1-157C552B394D/XCWorkspaceBuildGenerationPractise.app/Frameworks/SwiftProtobuf.framework/SwiftProtobuf
Symbol not found: _$s13SwiftProtobuf19_ProtoNameProvidingP17_protobuf_nameMapAA01_dH0VvgZTq
  Referenced from: /Users/<Mac-Name>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C1C95FC4-20C5-4C06-94D2-EFA435B83C04/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/97C2C91F-DDC8-49AE-8DE1-157C552B394D/XCWorkspacePractise.app/Frameworks/<ParentSDK>.framework/<ParentSDK>
  Expected in: /Users/<Mac-Name>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C1C95FC4-20C5-4C06-94D2-EFA435B83C04/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/97C2C91F-DDC8-49AE-8DE1-157C552B394D/XCWorkspacePractise.app/Frameworks/SwiftProtobuf.framework/SwiftProtobuf
```

I read some articles relate this issue, A lot of people says add swift-protobuf in your SDK locally. How to use this locally in my **ParentSDK**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the reason of this error. Still am using multiple version of swiftProtobuf. Before am used this case in like compile my xcframework with swiftprotobuf in **version 1**, once the xcframework generates successfully, Then use this compiled xcframework in my project, the xcframework wants some dependency include swiftprotobuf, Now am add swiftProtobuf dependency in **version 2**. That is the reason of this error.  So if anyone have this error, kindly once verify your dependency versions both are same.